# Sublime text not saving projects

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

Morning all.

I'm using an `iMac` at work, not out of choice, and I'm new to `OSX`. Been using it for month now, and don't really like it much. Anyway! Bit OT.

Using `ST3` to work, and I'm adding projects in the sidebar. Convenient. Until I close the application. I open it and all my projects are gone, meaning I need to re-add them EVERY time. It's annoying. I've googled it for about an hour, changed my sublime config, made sure I closed it properly each time using `CMD+Q` but nothing. It still doesn't save them!

Am I being an `iMac` noob, and missing something, or is this normal behavior for ST3 on `OSX`? (I'll add this in case it's any help.. I do the same at home on my Windows PC, and it saves them, so I turn my PC on, open `ST3`, and my projects are still there)

Cheers guys and gals.

Comment: I can say that I use ST3 on MacOS and while there are a couple of behaviours that different (by default, can be configured) so as to fit in with the Mac UI guidelines, this isn't one of them. How exactly are you adding the projects to the sidebar?

Comment: hmm okay. I've dragged the folder from finder, then added it into the sidebar. It then shows up but is then gone when I restart it :( I spotted something yesterday which looks like I can add folders, save it as a sublime project file, then use that, but I wasn't sure if it would have the same problem, and didn't have time to test it

Comment: I believe that would do it. Another possible problem might be the `hot_exit` setting. It defaults to true and when on it saves and restores open files and whatnot and restores them at startup.

Comment: @OdatNurd Ahh okay, gotcha, let me disable that and give it a test real quick..

Comment: Just realized I wasn't totally clear there; you probably want that to actually be set to 'true' but you may have set it to false. Besides that, I think having a project defined should probably do what you want (it should reload if `hot_exit` is turned on. The only other loophole would be closing the project window instead of pressing Command+Q to quit, but you already covered that.

Comment: Superb, I'll give that a go at work on Monday! Back home on my windows PC now :) <3 Thanks for your help mate, I'll let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing your cache? Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Within ST3? I'm not sure, I've had a look through preferences, and had a quick google, but couldn't find where to check this? Any ideas?

Comment: On Windown, if you clear your ST3 cache from a program like ccleaner all your tabs should be deleted, I don't use osx so I can't really tell you where to check ... sorry :(

Comment: Ahh I see - yeah my windows PC at home isn't the issue, it's the iMac I use at work :(